# Difference array to range array updates

Tags: algorithms

I found information that the best way to update ranges of array values is using difference array. It works but I can't figure out why it works.

Can anyone could explain it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a normal array of a bunch of values, a difference array derives the next value from the previous entries. Instead of

```
TheArray[] = {4,6,2,10};
```

You would have

```
DiffArray[] = {4,2,-4,8};
```

It helps to think of every positive value having a plus sign in front.  4+2 is 6. 6-4 is 2. 2+8 is 10. Same result, more math to get there.

It's "Best" in the case that shifting the entire array up and down can happen in O(1) time. No matter how big the array gets, shifting it all only takes one operation. But you can't just go get a value out of the array without adding up ALL the values that come before it, which would take significantly more processing overhead.   It's useful for a few niche cases.   ...I can't think of any off the top of my head.